# Join 4 tables in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

Have 4 relationship tables in my database and want to join them to get the total value... for instance i have friends, family, following and acquaintances and want to join these to get an "ALL" value.

The table formats are as such:

**Friends**

```
id follower following
---------------------
1     2      3
2     4      5
```

**Family**

```
id follower following
---------------------
1     5      6
2     7      8
```

**Following**

```
id follower following
---------------------
1     9      10
2     11     12
```

**Acquaintances**

```
id follower following
---------------------
1     13     14
2     15     16
```

Is the correct query to join all 4 tables...

```
SELECT following
FROM   friends
       INNER JOIN family ON friends.following=family.following
       INNER JOIN following ON friends.following=following.following
       INNER JOIN acquaintances ON friends.following=acquaintances.following
WHERE  follower='id'
```

Basically I want to join and retrieve the "following" value from all four tables where id= my id

Comment: depending on the amount of data in your tables, if you really want to get such simple queries, i would use "UNION" with a query for each table, should be a lot faster then joining all 4 tables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current query will only list a result if *all tables* have a link with your friends table. I believe you are more looking for something like this

```
SELECT following
FROM   friends
WHERE  follower='id'
UNION ALL 
SELECT following
FROM   family 
WHERE  follower='id'
UNION ALL 
SELECT following
FROM   following
WHERE  follower='id'
UNION ALL 
SELECT following
FROM   acquaintances 
WHERE  follower='id'
```

or a bit nicer to read and easier to adjust at the cost of some performance

```
SELECT following 
FROM   (
        SELECT following, follower FROM friends
        UNION ALL SELECT following, follower FROM family 
        UNION ALL SELECT following, follower FROM following
        UNION ALL SELECT following, follower FROM acquaintances 
       ) AS f
WHERE  follower='id'
```

[UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

> UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements
>   into a single result set.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do this:

```
SELECT following FROM friends WHERE follower='id'
UNION
SELECT following FROM family WHERE follower='id'
UNION
SELECT following FROM followers WHERE follower='id'
UNION
SELECT following FROM acquaintances WHERE follower='id'
```

Which will yield

```
following
---------------------
3
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
```

It might be better to stick friends, family, followers and acquaintances all in the same table though, unless the differences between these categories is big enough to merit their own tables.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. If I simplify your example to friends and family, joining them will return only people who are both friends and family, and allow you to extract ids from all tables in one row, which is pretty much useless.

What you want is a union, as the other answer suggest. However, a better choice might be to have one table of relationships that will have a special (enum?) column to define its type, instead of one table for every kind of relationship.

Answer (score 0):

as stated in my comment for this situation and depending on the amount of data you have in your x-tables i would use union:

```
(SELECT following FROM friends WHERE follower='id')
UNION
(SELECT following FROM family WHERE follower='id')
UNION
(SELECT following FROM following WHERE follower='id')
UNION
(SELECT following FROM acquaintances WHERE follower='id')
```

Answer (score 0):

you should redesign entity table.
friends, family, acquaintance can be separated by fields

```
id follower following type
---------------------------------
1     5      6        Family
2     7      8        Friends
3     13     14       Acquaintance 
4     15     16       Friends
```

then you can filter, order or grouping by `type`