# Select 4 different named columns across 4 tables and return the count of all

Tags: php, mysql

Ive been trying this for days, i want to count the amount of inactiveItems() from 4 tables, all help appreciated.

**The database**

**Tables**

- wcx_articles
- wcx_videos
- wcx_apps
- wcx_links

**The corresponding _active column for each table**

- article_active
- video_active
- app_active
- link_active

_active is a switch 1 or 0

**This is my current function - it returns 0**

```
 public function inactiveItems() {

$query = 
"SELECT * FROM wcx_articles,wcx_videos,wcx_apps,wcx_links 
WHERE wcx_articles.article_active='0' AND wcx_videos.video_active='0' 
AND wcx_apps.app_active='0' AND wcx_links.link_active='0'";

 if( $this->num_rows( $query ) > 0 ) {  
     $count = $this->num_rows($query);
     return $count;
     }      
 }

 public function num_rows( $query ) {
    $query = $this->link->query( $query );
    if( mysqli_error( $this->link ) ) {
        $this->log_db_errors( mysqli_error( $this->link ), $query, 'Fatal' );
        return mysqli_error( $this->link );
    }
    else {
        return mysqli_num_rows( $query );
    }
    mysqli_free_result( $query );
}
```

Comment: `OR` condition may help you instead of `AND`. `"SELECT * FROM wcx_articles,wcx_videos,wcx_apps,wcx_links 
WHERE wcx_articles.article_active='0' OR wcx_videos.video_active='0' 
OR wcx_apps.app_active='0' OR wcx_links.link_active='0'";`

Comment: Using OR instead of AND outputs the number 279

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
SELECT * inactives FROM wcx_articles WHERE article_active = 0
UNION
SELECT * inactives FROM wcx_videos WHERE video_active = 0
```

You have to do this for all other tables but it should give you an idea how to achieve what you want. This also means that the `wcx_` must have the same column names.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, i have done the following and it works. `SELECT * FROM wcx_articles WHERE article_active = '0'
UNION
SELECT * FROM wcx_videos WHERE video_active = '0'`

Comment: But if you have so many tables with the exact same structure you could do one table with an additional column `type` where you store the type of the record `article`, `video`, `app`, `link`.

Comment: Do you mean place all the items in one TABLE and have a selector `type` to distinguish them?

Comment: @CodeX exactly that would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you're doing could produce very unpredictable results. First of all you select from 4 tables at once so when the tables join up together the SQL goes crazy and might join but if there isn't a join command you can end up with a very weird context in the database. While this isn't the ideal solution you could try and write four separate queries that go:

```
Select Count(*) from wcx_articles where article_active = 0
```

This in turn will give you a single column with a single row of all the inactive articles. Retrieve that and run another queries. Eventually you will end up with a sum. You could also join tables which is also fine and would be somewhat like this:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   wcx_articles
WHERE  article_active = 0
UNION ALL 
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   wcx_videos 
WHERE  video_active = 0
UNION ALL 
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   wcx_apps
WHERE  apps_active=0
UNION ALL 
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   wcx_links 
WHERE  links_active='id'
```

This answer was inspired by this post and deserves its credit: [Join 4 tables in SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717967/join-4-tables-in-sql-query)

Comment: I have a function that returns the individual number of inactive items already and i could easily plus them together to get the overall amount but i need to be able to utilize the return in a conditional statement `if($count > 0) { do something }` i have noted your answer as something to read up on, thanks